# Scraping data from a pop-up window on a Java based website via R

Tags: r, web-scraping, popup

I'm trying to extract information from the following website:

http://rstats.immgen.org/PopulationComparison/

In this website, the data code names are in the drop-down list (for example under `Stem Cells`, `SC_LTSL_BM` and `SC_STSL_BM` etc.). When you click on these, a pop-up window shows up giving more information about that specific cell type. [Screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95RlW.png).

I'd like to scrape the first three elements (ie. `Short Name`, `Long Name`, and `Description`) from all the popup windows that can be visualized in this particular page.

What is the best way of doing this in R?

Thank you for the answers.

Comment: can you make sure that you are not violating terms of use when scrapping this website? after that, you can retrieve the underlying data from http://rstats.immgen.org/PopulationComparison/popinfo.txt using `read.csv("http://rstats.immgen.org/PopulationComparison/popinfo.txt", sep="\t")`

Comment: I don't think this annotation is protected by terms of use. In any event though I have obtained permission to download the actual data files from their servers. How did you find this `popinfo.txt` file under their website? I couldn't come across with it somehow

Comment: If you're familiar with the developer tools in Chrome/Firefox, you can look at the Javascript code (not Java!) powering the page, which refers to that datafile.

Comment: Hi Marius, I tried looking in the source code, but I can't seem to locate the link to the file. Where do you see it?